# How to add server variable in XSLT

Tags: javascript, c#, xslt

We are using xslt files in our project. In xslt files we are calling diffrent Javascripts file like :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <script language="javascript" src="Scripts\DainCSCommon.js"/>

</xsl:template match="/">
```

NOw what I want to append some ID in query string while including JS file to avoid the caching issue with each new release like

```
<script language="javascript" src="Scripts\DainCSCommon.js?RelNo=1"/>
```

Question is how can I make the `RelNo` value dynamic here like getting this value from config file or so

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
<xsl:variable name="h"><h/></xsl:variable>

<script language="javascript" src="Scripts\DainCSCommon.js?RelNo={generate-id($h)}">
</script>
```

Updated answer to get value from a file-

```
<xsl:variable name="h" select="unparsed-text('http://test.com/config.php')">

<script language="javascript" src="Scripts\DainCSCommon.js?RelNo={$h}">
    </script>
```

Assuming config.php generates a random number

Comment: Will it generate the ID for each request ? rite ? if yes then I am  looking for some other solution where I can define the RelID somewhere in config file and user That ID so that when there is new deployment it will take the ID from config file and server the latest JS file.

Comment: Hi Vinit, thanks, this solution looks good to me but I have one question do I need to keep a key with name 'h' in config file?